# Velocity.js 60+ FPS with more complex elements

Tags: javascript, html, animation, css-animations, velocity.js

Can anyone advise on how to get stable 60+ FPS with more complex elements and not only more or less empty divs?

An example i built for the purpose:
http://codepen.io/tommiehansen/full/JKiBG/

```
*(check/edit pen for source)*
```

I've read about CSS transforms to avoid etc but it still comes down to not always getting 60+ as soon as one has any sort of normal groups of elements to animate. The PEN uses 0 bad stuff such as box-shadow, border-radius etc.

Comment: Firstly, you don't want to get over 60 FPS, since most displays work around that number. Second, CSS transforms are not something you should avoid all together, it depends. And last, what in you pen is not animating fast enough?

Comment: Can't get over 60 FPS anyway since browsers lock at screen refresh rate (usually 55-60 FPS). But it's one thing to get 60 FPS and another to get *STABLE* 60 FPS without frame drops etc.

Nothing in the pen isn't animating fast enough, but it isn't about animations being fast it's about them being smooth 100% of the time (and not 90% -- no).